# Regex Replace in between

Tags: c#, regex

I have been trying real hard understanding regular expression,
Is there any way I can replace character(s) that is between two strings/
For example
I have

> sometextREPLACEsomeothertext

I want to replace , REPLACE (which can be anything in real work) **ONLY** between sometext and someothertext with other string.
Can anyone please help me with this.

**EDIT**
Suppose, my input string is

> sometext_REPLACE_someotherText_something_REPLACE_nothing

I want to replace REPLACE text in between sometext and someotherText
resulting following output

> sometext_THISISREPLACED_someotherText_something_REPLACE_nothing

Thank you

Comment: Why do you think regex is the right tool?

Comment: `"sometextREPLACEsomeothertext".Replace("REPLACE", "OtherText")`

Comment: @MatthiasKoch it does not , it will replace all the REPLACE text which is not what want, for example, if i have sometext_REPLACE_someotherText_one_REPLACE_two , it will replace all the REPLACE text.

Comment: @Oded other ideas are welcome as well :)

Comment: @41K: okay, but your question was not clear enough

Comment: You need to clarify your question - add example of what _shouldn't_ be changing etc...

Comment: Do you want Both "REPLACE" text replaced with "OtherText"?

Comment: @SomnathMuluk no, see the later edit.

Comment: @41K, in your example above, you are replacing the first occurrence of  the string "REPLACE_", not **anything in between anything else**.

Comment: @codesparkle, yes that is because, first REPLACE is only a valid entry that is between, sometext and someotherText, the last REPLACE is between something and nothing and that can not be replaced.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly you might want to use [lookahead and lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) for your regular expression

```
(?<=...)   # matches a positive look behind
(?=...)    # matches a positive look ahead
```

Thus

```
(?<=sometext)(\w+?)(?=someothertext)
```

would match any 'word' with at least 1 character following 'sometext' and followed by 'someothertext'

In C#:

```
result = Regex.Replace(subject, @"(?<=sometext)(\w+?)(?=someothertext)", "REPLACE");
```

Comment: Yes, this is pretty close, but still it seems like greedy match, can you make it lazy one.

Answer (score 0):

This is the regex to test if the string is valid.

```
\^.REPLACE.\
```

C# replace

```
string s = "sdfsdfREPLACEdhfsdg";
string v = s.Replace("REPLACE", "SOMETEXT");
```

Comment: Can't you just go s.Replace("sometext_REPLACE_other text", "sometext_TEXT_othertext")?